# Unity 3D Shadow Issues

Tags: unity-game-engine, shadow

I have object cube receive shadow and there is ball move beside the cube .

the problem is object receive shadow of the ball just in the beginning , like in this photo

[image: First Image with shadow issue]

after the ball move little bit , the shadow gone , the object stop receive shadow , like in this photo

[image: Shadow issue gone]

And also if the length of the object small like 1.5 , no receive shadow at all .

[image: still no shadow]

**Notice** : that problem just happen after build in the phone . in the editor everything work good .

Comment: what kind of light and rendering path are you using?

Comment: Try increasing the shadow distance in Quality Settings for moble platform

Comment: joreldraw -  the problem in all type of lights . i am using use graphics setting in rendering path. ...                                                                         ZayedUpal - I tried to increasing the shadow distance , same problem

Comment: I tried forward in rending path but still same Issues
.

Comment: Have you checked Edit>Project Settings>Quality>Shadows>Hard and Soft Shadows  ? In low quality, the mobile builds avoids shadows, as this effect is costly on this platform.

Comment: It is in Hard and Soft Shadows . I also tried  hard shadow only but still same issues